# ICU CurrencyFormatter pattern for 0 digits

Tags: php, localization, icu

I am trying to get the localized currency symbol using the NumberFormatter in PHP's intl extension.

Since the NumberFormatter uses ICU, I am looking at this [page](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html).

I have written the following code:

```
$currencyFormatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$currencyFormatter->setPattern('¤');
echo $currencyFormatter->formatCurrency(0, 'USD');
```

Now the code works, but even though I have set the pattern to just the currency symbol, I will always get 1 digit.

The above code outputs

```
$0
```

Changing     `echo $currencyFormatter->formatCurrency(8, 'USD');` gives `$8`.

Are there any patterns I can use so that the digits are never displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is for php intl to expose ICU's [`ucurr_getName(...,UCURR_SYMBOL_NAME,...)`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucurr_8h.html#a99e4d6409d1c015a6c331aa87fe1863b%20ucurr_getName%28%29) - maybe file a feature request with php intl.